# Best language to build a Raspberry Pi User Interface

Tags: user-interface

I would like to create a user interface to control a Raspberry Pi movable arm via USB. What is the best programming language to use that will allow me to create both a user interface and interact with Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1):

With the question of what is the "best" you are going to draw too many opinions.
The question I would ask is ....

**Where will the UI exist?**

- Native
- Web
- API

The "best" is probably the one you are most familiar with to be honest. With all the new tech these days (given there still are considerations) you should be able to deploy to any of those locations in a fair amount of time and get your UI to signal your robot arm.

As far as  your hardware side of things, I think many frameworks in a number of the languages support a good number of those as well. Here are a few examples.

- http://gobot.io/
- https://cylonjs.com/
- http://artoo.io/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Tkinter in python for making a GUI. But, if you want to interface with the pi through the internet, you can use the https://thingsboard.io interface.

This tutorial shows you how to use [guizero](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/about/), which is a wrapper for tkinter(making it even easier to use) -
https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-guis

You should also checkout the dedicated stackexchange forum for pi for more related answers-
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/recommended-gui-toolkit-for-python-development-on-the-raspberry-pi